# Importing ReactDOM doesn't render anything

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm pretty new to React and I've been trying to set up a REACT app. However, I always get a blank page. Can anyone help?

**HTML Code** (index.html)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript** (index.js)

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

const page = (
  <div>
    <h1>My page</h1>
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(page, document.getElementById("root"));
```

And yes, I am using a live server to run this code.

Comment: check if there are any errors in the console. How are you running the app?

Comment: I'm using the "Live Server" extension in Visual Studio Code and the only errors is

DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/scripts/iframe_form_detection.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Answer (score 1):

Browsers don't understand the `text/babel` MIME type.

It is there for Babel to search the DOM for scripts that it should process to convert from whatever they are (JS + JSX in this case) to JS.

You haven't included Babel in your page though.

You have a further problem in that inside your script you have `import` statements which depend on Node.js module resolution (and you're using a browser, not Node).

---

You should start at the beginning of [the React guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html#try-react).

You currently have an odd mix of about 20% of [the quick guide to adding React to a website](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) and 5% of [using a Node.js based toolchain to transpile your code](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#recommended-toolchains).

---

I recommend starting with [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app) as it gives you a robust, performant foundation to get started with.